# How to spawn a grandchild process for a child process?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have spawned a child process, below is the code:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr'], { detached: true });

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  fs.writeFileSync('path-to-test.txt', 'stdout');
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  fs.writeFileSync('path-to-test.txt', 'stderr');
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

With option `detached: true`, it will keep the child process running even the parent process is killed.

My question is: how to run a grandchild process under this child process? Because in my senario, after spawn this child process, the parent process will be killed. So I can't spawn another process, except using existing child process to spawn a grandchild process.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to note that the detached option only keeps the child alive after the parent dies on a Windows system. In Unix systems, the child will stay alive by default.

In order to spawn a "grandchild process", `child_program.js` would have to spawn a child process as well. Try this example out to see. Suppose you have `app.js` which contains the following:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn(process.argv[0], [__dirname + '/child_program.js'], {
 detached: true,
 stdio: 'ignore'
});

child.unref();
```

And then suppose, `child_program.js` contains the following:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const child = spawn(process.argv[0], [__dirname + '/grandchild_program.js'], {
 detached: true,
 stdio: 'ignore'
});

child.unref();
```

And lastly, let's say `grandchild_program.js` does this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/bob.txt', 'bob was here', 'utf-8');
```

Create these files, put them in the same directory, run `node app.js` and then you should see `bob.txt` show up in that same directory. Let me know if you have any questions. My question to you would be if you know what `process.argv[0]` gives you and why you're spawning new child processes with that argument.

Comment: I know the value of process.argv[0] is from command line argument, but I am sorry, I put the wrong code there, and is corrected now. So I only have one file 'app.js' with a child process to run a simple command, and then it should spawn a grandchild process to run another simple command. That's it.

Comment: @Ng2-Fun: You're misunderstanding what child process is. You're NOT running a child process to run a simple command. That simple command IS your child process.