# Node.js child process with detached option

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process, squirrel.windows

I am creating an electron desktop app, and I have code use spawn() with option detached: true. My purpose is to let the child process keep running even when the parent process terminated.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr'], { detached: true });

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  fs.writeFileSync('path-to-test.txt', 'stdout');
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
  fs.writeFileSync('path-to-test.txt', 'stderr');
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

squirrel events https://github.com/electron/grunt-electron-installer#handling-squirrel-events:

```
  switch (squirrelCommand) {
    case '--squirrel-install':
    case '--squirrel-updated':
      app.quit();

      return true;
    case '--squirrel-uninstall':
      app.quit();
      return true;
    case '--squirrel-obsolete':
      return true;
  }
```

I tested the above code outside of squirrel events, it works well when the parent process is alive. But after I put these code inside squirrel events like `--squirrel-uninstall` (the parent process may terminated before/during child process run), it can only run commands, any code inside it (like fs function) doesn't work any more.

My have a question is: despite of squirrel event, can the logic code like fs inside child process work after the node parent process terminate?

Comment: How do you know that the callback functions are not working?

Comment: @HaydenBraxton - after I put my child process code inside squirrel event, it will not create a file, and write info into it. Which means the fs function doesn't work there.